# Install linux from within windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux

I have an old Windows 7 Toshiba Tecra A9 with a locked BIOS which won't let me boot off anything but the internal hard drive. I sadly lost the BIOS password a long time ago. I am however administrator on this machine. Is it possible somehow to replace windows by linux in such a situation?

Comment: A simple way that wouldn't require any special software or learning curve if you have another computer: remove the hard disk, use a USB adapter to connect it to the other computer and install it there.  The adapters are inexpensive and have an IDE or SATA connector on one side and a USB plug on the other (check your local electronics store, Amazon, etc.).

Comment: @fixer1234 that's a nice idea. I hadn't thought of that option.

Comment: @Lembik where are you? read mine? http://superuser.com/a/816892/354352 accept it and close this question. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wubi https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide or you can try to remove the password by using http://thegeekdaily.com/easily-reset-bios-password-with-pc-cmos-cleaner/ or by taking apart the laptop and removing for a few seconds the cmos battery.

Comment: You seem to need to be able to boot off a CD for http://thegeekdaily.com/easily-reset-bios-password-with-pc-cmos-cleaner/ or did I get that wrong?

Comment: This hasnt been support by Ubuntu for 2 years..

Comment: Doh, of course, your two options are: wubi( Ubuntu 12 is lts, it's still actual) and tearing apart the laptop

Answer (score 2):

Real nice solution. Are you familiar with PLOP?
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/
Just download it and save it then you need EasyBCD
http://www.filehorse.com/download-easybcd/
Then you should configure EasyBCD to boot from your iso file
[image: STH]

Then you should be able to see a new option on boot. Enter it and you will something like this:

[image: AnotherThing!]

Which enables you to boot from anything you like. CHEERS!

Comment: That's what I would do. PLOP is an absolute live-saver to deal with weird boot/startup issues.

Comment: This requires the ability to boot from a CD or floppy in order to install it.  The problem in this case is inability to boot from anything but the hard disk.  If the system could boot from a CD, there wouldn't be a problem installing Linux.

Comment: @fixer1234 No when using EasyBCD it chnages the MBR and add the iso file record to it. so when you boot your computer there is two option one is windows and another is PLOP so you select PLOP which is a virtual boot manager then you can do other things like booting from CD or Flash drive. It does not require CD or sth, It just needs the ability to login to windows.