# Installing Linux without access to a keyboard or screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi

I need to do an unattended install of Linux on a Windows 10 machine without a screen or a keyboard for dual-booting; or replacing Windows entirely if that's easier. I can access the machine remotely to run commands.

I've managed to create a USB-stick that does the installation without requiring any user input, but I believe I will still need to access the BIOS and change the boot order for it to work.

Is there any way to force the machine to boot from the USB when it restarts?

Comment: Are you trying to dual-boot or replace Windows? According to [this SuperUser posting](https://superuser.com/questions/816860/install-linux-from-within-windows-7) PlOP & EacyBCD might help. Needing a Linux running _ON_ the Win system as your question suggests, WSL or other VM would be my choice. Depends on your exact need.

Comment: I'm trying to dual-boot, Windows is just my starting point. If it's easier to just replace Windows then that is also an option. Thanks for the info, I'll have a look!

Comment: Are you booting with UEFI or in legacy/BIOS mode?

Comment: We are booting with UEFI

Comment: Just to clarify, the whole process did actually work on my test machine without having to use a keyboard, but I suspect it's because I have messed with the BIOS earlier and changed the boot order.